# Magento 1.9 Not Showing Category and Products in Front End

Tags: magento, smtp

Category as well as Products not Showing in Front End,

I am doing below Steps,

```
Step 1:       Catalog->Manage Categories->Click Add Root Category.
 1.2:     In that Page i  filled Name like electronics and is_active column Yes and Include in Navigation Menu  Yes in General Settings and then save Category.
Step 2:      Catalog->Manage Products->Click Add Root Category.Step 3:      Click Add Product Step 4:      Attribute Set = Default and Product Type = Simple Product Step 5:      In General tab-> Filed Name => Washing MAchine ,Description => Something , Short Description =>Something,SKU => 4555,weight => 56,Status=>Enabled,Visibility => catalog search Step 6:      In Prices tab-> Filed Price => 3 and Tax class => None Step 7:      Inventory Tab -> Filled Qty =>5 and Stock Availability =>In stock Step 8:      Website Tab->Select Website  Step 9:     Select Categories Step 10:    Saved Products Step 11:  System->Cache Management Click Flush MAgento Cache and Select all disable all cache management Data Step 12 :  System->Index Management Select all reindex data.
```

My Category Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Step 3:
[image]

Step 4:
[image]

Manage Products:

Step1:
 [image]

Step 2:
[image]

Step 3:
[image]

Step4:
[image]

Step 5:

[image]

My front end always look like..

[image]

Comment: Can you please share backend category page screenshot

Comment: Ya Upload my category and products page in backend

Comment: You are finding products on home page.
try <your_ul>/<category_url>

Note:- re-index catalog url

Comment: Sorry,can't understand <your_ul>/<category_url> this where i changed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the shared screenshot you have created category on Root level. Root Category don't show on frontend. You need to create child categories in Root category.

For this Select Electronic Category and then click on `Add sub Category` button to add category in root category.

Also Please make sure in your Store correct Root category is selected. You can check this from `System` >> `Manage Stores` top navigation.

This may also help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qLqRsUN58Uc